# Display searched Item base on user input

Tags: flutter, search

I'm trying to display a `result item` following the user input in the text field, but I receive all the items. There were some methods I tried, but they didn't work and I encountered some errors.

[image]

here is my source code

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:ebook_flutter_app/constant.dart';
import 'package:ebook_flutter_app/model/image.dart';
import 'package:ebook_flutter_app/model/text_value.dart';
import 'package:ebook_flutter_app/screens/show_item.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:persistent_bottom_nav_bar/persistent-tab-view.dart';

import '../widgets/showImage.dart';

class SearchScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SearchScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  SearchScreenState createState() => SearchScreenState();
}

class SearchScreenState extends State<SearchScreen> {
  List textValues = [];
  List original = [];
  List result = [];
  TextEditingController txtQuery = TextEditingController();

  List<TextValue> textValueList = [];
  List<MyImage> myImageList = [];

  List<TextValue> getCatList(List<TextValue> inputList, String query) {
    List<TextValue> outputList =
        inputList.where((item) => item.title == query).toList();
    
    //textValueList = outputList;
    //var myList = outputList;
    return outputList;
  }

  List<MyImage> getImageList(List<MyImage> inputList, String query) {
    List<MyImage> outputList =
        inputList.where((o) => o.id_num!.toString() == query).toList();
    // myImageList = outputList;
    return outputList;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    txtQuery.addListener(() {
      if (isNumeric(txtQuery.text) == true) {
        loadImage();
        searchById(txtQuery.text);
        print('I\'m using search option for loading Image.... ');
      } else {
        loadData();
        search(txtQuery.text);
        print('I\'m using search option for loading Data....');
      }
    });
  }

  void loadData() async {
    String jsonStr = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/db/text_value.json');
    var json = jsonDecode(jsonStr);
    textValues = json;
    original = json;
    setState(() {});
  }

  void loadImage() async {
    String jsonStr = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/db/image_db.json');
    var json = jsonDecode(jsonStr);
    textValues = json;
    original = json;
    print('load Image is running....');
    setState(() {});
  }

  void search(String query) {
    if (query.isEmpty) {
      textValues = original;
      setState(() {});
      return;
    }

    query = query.toLowerCase();
    print(query);
    //List result = [];
    textValues.forEach((element) {
      var name = element["name"].toString().toLowerCase();
      var description = element["description"].toString().toLowerCase();
      if (name.contains(query) || description.contains(query)) {
        result.add(element);
        // textValueList.add(element);
        // print('textValueList is $textValueList');
      }
    });

    textValues = result;
    setState(() {});
  }

  void searchById(String query1) {
    if (query1.isEmpty) {
      textValues = original;
      print('query1 is .....$query1');
      setState(() {});
      return;
    }

    print('query1 is $query1');
    //List result = [];
    textValues.forEach((element) {
      var id_num = element["id_num"].toString();
      var img_num = element["img_num"].toString();
      if (id_num.contains(query1)) {
        result.add(element);
        // myImageList.add(element);
        //         print('mYImageList is $myImageList');

        print('result is......$result');
      }
    });

    textValues = result;
    print('textValues is .....$textValues');
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: CustomAppBar(2),
      body: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: txtQuery,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {});
                    },
                    textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "جست وجو...",
                      hintTextDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 18,
                        fontFamily: 'iran-sans-ds',
                        decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                        fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                      ),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0)),
                      focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black)),
                      prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.clear),
                        onPressed: () {
                          txtQuery.text = '';
                          txtQuery.clear();
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            txtQuery.text.isEmpty
                ? Container()
                : Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: textValues.length,
                        // isNumeric(txtQuery.text) == true
                        //     ? getImageList(myImageList, txtQuery.text).length
                        //     : getCatList(textValueList, txtQuery.text).length,

                        
                        
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          var textVal = textValues[index];
                          String description = textVal['description'] ??
                              'we don\'t have description......';

                          var id_num = textVal['id_num'].toString() ??
                              'we don\'t have id_num......';
                          var img_num = textVal['img_num'].toString() ??
                              'we don\'t have img_num........... ';

                          print('id_num is ....$id_num'
                              ' img_num is.....$img_num');

                          return Card(
                            margin:
                                const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 4.0, 8.0, 4.0),
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
                            color: Colors.blue[50],
                            child: Theme(
                              data: Theme.of(context)
                                  .copyWith(dividerColor: Colors.transparent),
                              child: InkWell(
                                onTap: (() => pushNewScreen(
                                      context,
                                      screen: isNumeric(id_num) == false
                                          ? ShowItem(
                                              name: textVal['name'],
                                              description:
                                                  textVal['description'],
                                            )
                                          : ShowImage(
                                              title: id_num,
                                              image: Myasset(img_num),
                                            ),
                                      withNavBar:
                                          true, // OPTIONAL VALUE. True by default.
                                      pageTransitionAnimation:
                                          PageTransitionAnimation.slideRight,
                                    )),
                                child: ExpansionTile(
                                  title: Text(
                                    isNumeric(id_num) == false
                                        ? textVal['name']
                                        : id_num,
                                    textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.black54),
                                  ),
                                  childrenPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      bottom: 20.0,
                                      right: 20.0,
                                      left: 20.0,
                                      top: 5.0),
                                  children: [
                                    isNumeric(id_num) == false
                                        ? Row(
                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                            children: [
                                                const Text(
                                                  'بیشتر',
                                                  textDirection:
                                                      TextDirection.rtl,
                                                  textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      color: Colors.blue,
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.bold),
                                                ),
                                                Text(
                                                  '${description.substring(0, 39)} ...',
                                                  textDirection:
                                                      TextDirection.rtl,
                                                  textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      color: Colors.black),
                                                ),
                                              ])
                                        : Image.asset(
                                            Myasset(img_num),
                                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                            width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                    .size
                                                    .width *
                                                0.01,
                                            height: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                    .size
                                                    .height *
                                                0.01,
                                          ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        }),
                  )
          ]),
    );
  }
}

Widget _listView(text_value) {
  return Expanded(
    child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: text_value.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          var textVal = text_value[index];
          String description =
              textVal['description'] ?? 'we don\'t have description......';

          var id_num =
              textVal['id_num'].toString() ?? 'we don\'t have id_num......';
          var img_num = textVal['img_num'].toString() ??
              'we don\'t have img_num........... ';

          print('id_num is ....$id_num' ' img_num is.....$img_num');

          return Card(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 4.0, 8.0, 4.0),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
            color: Colors.blue[50],
            child: Theme(
              data:
                  Theme.of(context).copyWith(dividerColor: Colors.transparent),
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: (() => pushNewScreen(
                      context,
                      screen: isNumeric(id_num) == false
                          ? ShowItem(
                              name: textVal['name'],
                              description: textVal['description'],
                            )
                          : ShowImage(
                              title: id_num,
                              image: Myasset(img_num),
                            ),
                      withNavBar: true, // OPTIONAL VALUE. True by default.
                      pageTransitionAnimation:
                          PageTransitionAnimation.slideRight,
                    )),
                child: ExpansionTile(
                  title: Text(
                    isNumeric(id_num) == false ? textVal['name'] : id_num,
                    textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                    style:
                        const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.black54),
                  ),
                  childrenPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      bottom: 20.0, right: 20.0, left: 20.0, top: 5.0),
                  children: [
                    isNumeric(id_num) == false
                        ? Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                            children: [
                                const Text(
                                  'بیشتر',
                                  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.blue,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  '${description.substring(0, 39)} ...',
                                  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                ),
                              ])
                        : Image.asset(
                            Myasset(img_num),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.01,
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.01,
                          ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }),
  );
}
```

I didn't use  `getCatList` & `myImageList`methods because I encountered to error when I was using this methods.

> How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Inside addListener you're calling loadData() every single time the user enter a character. Try this:

```
void initState() {
super.initState();
loadData();
txtQuery.addListener(() {
  search(txtQuery.text);
});
```

}

The second thing you could try is use for in instead of forEach

```
void search(String query) {
if (query.isEmpty) {
  textValues = [];
  setState(() {});
  return;
}

setState(() {
  textValues = [
    for (var item in yourDataSource)
      if (item['key'].contains(query)) item
  ];
});
```

}

And you can use textValues in your list

```
body: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: textValues.length,
```

Comment: What do you mean by `yourDataSource`? 

Can you suggest an alternative to `yourDataSource` in my project?

Comment: In your code the List original variable would be your data source because is where you put that json data. So you can use it: for (var item in original) and the 'key' would be name and description if you ask for both if (item['name'].contains(query) || ... )

Answer (score 0):

You can use autocomplete textfield for your problem

check this plugin :

https://pub.dev/packages/auto_complete_search

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any function for `onChanged` (TextFormField's argument), let's try this:

First edit your `search()` function

```
         void search(String query) {
                if (query.isEmpty) {
                  setState(() {
                   textValues = original;
                  });
                  return;
                }
            setState(() {
            textValues = original.where( (element) => 
   element['name'].contains(query.toLowerCase()).toString().toLowerCase() || 
  element['description'].contains(query.toLowerCase()).toString().toLowerCase()
    ).toList();
                });
              }
```

Second edit `onChanged` argument

```
onChanged: (value) => search(value)
```